# How can I get past the Bone Heat Weighting error on my character armature and mesh?

Tags: mesh, armature, parent

I know this has been discussed before, but I'm looking for fresh ideas. I created the character mesh and the armature, and get the *Bone Heat Weighting* error even after doing the steps many have recommended. (Re-meshing, resizing, etc.).

I made sure that the armature has all the bones for my purposes, and wonder if I'm missing some Parenting on the bones? I don't think so, but I still can't get a successful parenting action when I try to apply it. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Mesh and Armature]
[image: Armature Only]

Comment: This looks pretty high poly for what you'd want to autoweight.  Bone parenting doesn't matter.  For any help, peeps would need a file.

Comment: UPDATE: I got the rig to parent after making sure that my mesh was fully symmetrical. I am also needing to manually weight the fingertips, but it's working out so far.